# Render game frames

Tags: android, render, game-development

I am making a game.
My code is something like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(playfield.GFX, playfield.X, playfield.Y, paint);
canvas.drawBitmap(player.GFX, player.X, player.Y, paint);
canvas.drawBitmap(score.GFX, score.X, score.Y, paint);
```

Is it correct or is better to draw all in memory and after display the rendered image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Drawing image in memory and displaying after is known as [Multiple buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering) (quiet often it is [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics)) and this is good practice for game development.